# Implementing Bootstrap Affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-affix

I have a page with h1 and content in `<p>` tag, like this:

```
<h1>Content1</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>

<h1>Content2</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>

<h1>Content3</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>

<h1>Content4</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>

<h1>Content5</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>
```

I want to implement Bootstrap Affix float on the right, like Bootstrap official page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

But i don't know how, i don't understand the instructions, i need to put this:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  ...
</div>
```

And this:

```
$('#my-affix').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
    , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
```

How can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need both, you can only use HTML markup. But you need to put <a href="#id">...</a> and <h1 id="id">...</h1>

Comment: What i need to insert between <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
</div> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try an Affix menu generator called [Appizy](http://appizy.com). You just have to create spreadsheet with your title (h1) in a column and the content (p) in a second column, Appizy creates the good tags and javascript for you. Here you have [a tutorial video.](http://youtu.be/QZTV8UPQEbk)

Answer (score 0):

As I have said, you can only use HTML markup :

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#title-1">Title 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#title-2">Title 2</a></li>
    ....
  </ul>
</div>
```

And for your content :

```
<h1 id="title-1">Content1</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>

<h1 id="title-2">Content2</h1>
<p>Blablablalbal</p>
...
```

Comment: I won't do your job ! Create your fiddle and try my code. Did you allready try it ?

Comment: Yes i tried it but the affix goes to left and when i pass to my h1 it not change the class to active. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33p6D/ I want to float affix to the right not the left, and add a class active to the current li when it pass the title, for example if i'm over the title 2, add class active to the title 2, like boostrap official affix.